# Readme.io - How to indent multiline list item

Tags: list, markdown

How do I indent a multiline list item so that the designator so that both lines are flush left and the designor (in this case the d) is outside of them to the left.

[image]

So it appears like this:

[image]

I've tried two spaces at the end of first line with a break, placing 
 where I want the break to happen, indenting manually, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of indenting manually, just let the line run on:

```
1. **Expired:** a post that was once live, but has been removed from the Suggested Library either manually by an admin, or reached its set expiration date
```

If you must break the line manually, indent further lines by four spaces, e.g.

```
1. **Expired:** a post that was once live,
    but has been removed from the Suggested
    Library either manually by an admin, or
    reached its set expiration date
```

This will work by default in most Markdown implementations I'm aware of, though bear in mind that Markdown itself is only concerned with *content*. Presentation rules (e.g. CSS) can further modify presentation, including alignment of lists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Letting the line run on resulted in what I posted (and was why I posted) as I was under the impression the Markdown converter would do as you said. I then put in a hard break and tried indenting four spaces, as described in the readme.io docs but it doesn't work for me. Be nice if I could turn on invisibles to see if there was some fragment or something that could be causing the issue.

Comment: Then it's probably just the way that product chooses to style lists. You can try inspecting the CSS using your browser's developer tools and see.

Comment: For any future person coming here the issue was that I was copying the list items out of a MS Word doc and pasting into readme.io. At least that is my thought. Word must have a lot of fragments or other junk embedded within it and that was messing up the HTML convertor. Anyway, manually redoing it solved the issue.